# Input está "Cortando" o que vem depois do espaço com o PHP

Tags: php, javascript, html

Tenho uma tela de alteração de cadastro. As informações que serão alteradas eu trago para um campo de input, permitindo que o usuário mexa caso necessário.

porém, ocorre um problema caso a palavra seja separada por 'espaço', ou seja, se o usuário digita `"Olá mundo"`, só vai pro campo input `"Olá"`.

HTML:

```
<a a class="arib">Origem: </a><input type="text" maxlength="40" placeholder="Origem" value=<?php echo $Origem; ?> name="origem" style="width:50px;"/>
```

PHP:

```
<?php
$Origem = "Olá Mundo";
?>
```

Comment: Coloque  "var_dump($Origem)" no seu código, um pouco antes de usar a variável. Com isso vai poder saber melhor se o problema está na hora do echo ou se a variável está sendo distorcida. Se possível cole aqui seu código PHP  do momento de criação da variável até o uso dela.

Comment: Lá tá saindo completo "Olá Mundo", mas no input continua saindo só "Olá"

Comment: O codigo q estou aplicando teste é o de cima, fiz o teste com a frase "Olá mundo" direto na variável, e ficou da mesma forma

Comment: Teste isso em seu código. 

    <?php
        $Origem = "Olá Mundo";
    ?>

    <input type="text" placeholder="Origem" value="<?php echo $Origem; ?>"/>

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seu `value=<?php echo $Origem; ?>` deve ser `value="<?php echo $Origem; ?>"`

Answer (score 1):

Meio sem nexo digitar `Olá mundo` em um campo que só aceitará números, mas vou publicar minha resposta

Pelo que vi no código, quem não deixa digitar mais que 4 caracteres é o tal do `maxlength="4"`

> O atributo `maxlength` especifica o comprimento máximo do valor que pode ser inserido

**Então Olá + um espaço somam um comprimento = 4**

```html
<a a class="arib">Origem: </a><input type="text" maxlength="4" placeholder="Origem" value="" name="origem" style="width:220px;"/>
```

Segundo comentário do AP `Eu havia digitado errado no exemplo acima, mas no meu código estava um 40, o que solucionou o problema foi a solução do amigo Wess acima,` não creio que o problema tenha sido a falta de aspas no `value`, visto que o value sempre possui um valor preenchido pelo php `<?php echo $Origem; ?>` Para comprovar coloquei um exemplo abaixo que mesmo sem aspas funciona a contento.

```html
<a a class="arib">Origem: </a><input type="text" maxlength="40" placeholder="Origem" value=12  name="origem" style="width:50px;"/>
```

Comment: Eu havia digitado errado no exemplo acima, mas no meu código estava um 40, o que solucionou o problema foi a solução do amigo Wess acima, mas agradeço por notar esse erro na minha pergunta já está corrigido :D

Comment: Havia me equivocado e colocado um exemplo errado na questão, corrigi a pergunta com o campo certo e com as instruções certas, reafirmo que a resposta do Wess funcionou muito bem, pois no meu código estava tudo certo